# Resizing image to perfectly fit a div with variable dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I need to scale an image inside a *div* properly, so that the image keeps its proportions and so that either the width is equal to 100% or the height is equal to 100%.
So basically that the image takes up as much space as possible in the *div* whilst maintaining aspect ratio. And lets keep in mind that the div can change width and height.

So I have the intuition for this, but I don't have the code ...

> The idea would be to get the ratio (height/width) of the div with
>   *JavaScript*/*jQuery*. => ratio A    Then get ratio (height/width) of the image. => ratio B
>
> **Note:** If ratio > 1, then we have a portrait image or div.
>   And if ratio < 1, then we have a landscape image or div.
>
> If ratio A < ratio B, then we want height of image to be set at 100%; 
>   If ratio A > ratio B, then we want width of image to be set at 100%;

So if we have a responsive *div*, width or height = 100% will change dynamically.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-css-object-fit-object-position-properties/

Comment: If you want to use jquery, there are some plugins you can use. https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid https://github.com/periplox/jquery.imagefit https://github.com/gestixi/image-scale

Comment: @Paulie_D Had no idea they was such a plain simple solution with CSS... Thanks =)

Comment: Does it have to be an `<img>`, or could you use a background image with CSS?

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier Had to be <img> tag

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2(css) solutions  :

1. http://codepen.io/cryptcslaughtr/pen/LNoMBY

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: url("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png") no-repeat left top / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/cryptcslaughtr/pen/qZGLvE

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" alt="Put your image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your first CSS code works but i need to keep the <im> tag
And the second CSS code doesn't work if the image is smaller than the div

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set parent div to position relative, and overflow hidden. And then do this:

```
.bg-img {
   bottom: -1000px;
   left: -1000px;
   margin: auto;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   right: -1000px;
   top: -1000px;
}
```

This will insure no matter whats the size of the container it will always cover it 100%. This will also contain image proportions.

Comment: Paulie_D gave an even easier CSS solution that i didn't at all realize ...
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-css-object-fit-object-position-properties/

Comment: Did you check browser support for it? http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit object-fit isn't supported on any IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need img tag for SEO/alt/ARIA/whatever, here is modified Cryptc_Slaughtr's solutions combined into one:

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: url("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png") no-repeat left top / contain;
}
.container img {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" alt="Put your image" title="Put your image" /></div>
```